# Matrox Imaging library with JNI hangs during buffer read

Tags: c, image-processing, java-native-interface, frame-grab, matrox

I had the following code to get an array in JNI.

```
jfloat *ptr = (*env)->GetFloatArrayElements(env, array, 0);
```

To copy MIL buffer to User array used the below matrox api with above `*ptr`(as UserArrayPtr) it works fine:

```
void MbufGet(MIL_ID srcBifId, void *UserArrayPtr)
```

Due to out of memory error i changed the logic to below (to not make a copy):

```
jfloat *ptr = (*env)->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(env, array, 0);
```

and with this the `MbufGet()` call hangs and its not coming out of it.

I am not able to query the error (if any) as its hanged at this call.

Is there any way to overcome this ?

Comment: Do you _need_ a `float[]` on the Java side or can you survive with a `FloatBuffer`? If so you can wrap `FloatBuffer` around a **direct** `ByteBuffer`, which allows you to get the address of the underlying allocation directly on the native side.

Comment: Yes I need a float[] , but since this is failing I am trying out Direct ByteBuffer. Though it requires a lot of change I don’t see any other way to overcome this .

Comment: @Botje Could you please help on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657638/jni-get-the-array-pointer-from-getdirectbufferaddress