# JNI get the array pointer from GetDirectBufferAddress

Tags: c, image-processing, java-native-interface, frame-grab, matrox

This is a follow up on the below question:

[Matrox Imaging library with JNI hangs during buffer read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77645958/matrox-imaging-library-with-jni-hangs-during-buffer-read)

Since `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical` was not working i opted for Direct `ByteBuffer` and below is my java side code:

```
 ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(arr.length * 4); // arr is a float array
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer fb = buffer.asFloatBuffer();
    fb.put(arr);
    fb.position(0);

native int calculate(FloatBuffer fb);
```

and in *JNI* side i have the following code:

```
JNIExport jint JNICALL Java_com_test_calculate(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject arr){ // the arr has the buffer

jfloat *ptr = NULL

void *temp = (*env) -> GetDirectBufferAddress(env, arr);
*ptr = *(jfloat *)&temp;
...
...
MBufGet(srcBuf, ptr); //matrox imaging lib call - This has to fill the array from srcBuf

}
```

and in java i access it by:

```
float[] arr  = new float[buffer.capacity()/4];
for(int i=0; i<buffer.capacity()/4;i++){
arr[i] = buffer.getFloat();
}
```

This has no errors but the retrieved arr contains only 0's / or not updating the buffer.

These logic works if i use the below code(with `GetFloatArrayElements`):

```
JNIExport jint JNICALL Java_com_test_calculate(JNIEnv *env,jobject obj, jfloatArray arr){ // the arr has the buffer
jfloat *ptr = NULL 
*ptr = (*env) -> GetFloatArrayElements(env, arr, 0);
...
...
MBufGet(srcBuf, ptr); //matrox imaging lib call - This has to fill the array from srcBuf
}
```

I assume its working because it has a actual array's pointer itself and in direct buffer case some thing is wrong.

How can i make the direct `GetDirectBufferAddress` to return a similar type as what `GetFloatArrayElements` returns in JNI.

Comment: For converting from `FloatBuffer` back to a `float[]` (but note this is a copy, which you wanted to avoid ..) you can also use `buffer.asFloatBuffer().get(arr)`.

Answer (score 2):

You completely bungled the cast. It should be

```
jfloat *ptr = (jfloat *)((*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, arr));
```

Comment: MBufGet is still not copying to the array after this change as well . Maybe the MBufGet itself cannot write to it !

Comment: "copying to the array"? The floatbuffer object is completely distinct from the float array.